# Designating ranges relative to the cell in which the triggering button is placed

Tags: excel, vba, button

I'm trying to build a modular table which can be copied and pasted around a sheet ad nauseum. I'm building it with a macro that will perform a task based on references relative to the button which fired the macro (which will be an integrated part of the table).

Setting of the ranges is proving very challenging. I've been using the below macro to test range-setting relative to a button. None of the *greened out* lines will fire.

X is a cell positioned -1,-1
A is a range positioned (1,-1: 23,-1)

In the code below I attempted first without selecting the button cell.

I then tried selecting the button cell.
With the button cell selected, I used both the offset functions and the `offset.resize` options.

I found posts here which describe setting ranges relative to active cells but these always include the active cell in the range which wouldn't work for this, since the button needs to be well clear of the data.

Since the universal factor in all of these attempts is the `Application.Caller`, is this not the correct phrase?

```vb
Sub RelateiveBttn()

Dim Arange As Range, XRange As Range
 
'Set Arange = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Range(Offset(1, -1)): ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Range (Offset(23, -1))

ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Select
 
'Set XRange = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1))
'Set Arange = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Resize(23, 0)
'Set Arange = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1), ActiveCell.Offset(23, -1))

Arange.Select

XRange.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to move the button relative to the actual button position?

Comment: A button isn't actually "in" a cell. Normally one would use `Shape.TopLeftCell` here.

Comment: I don't think it's right to make a decision about what a program will do from the position of a button, you should find a more logical way, for example from the cell that the user will select before pressing the button... or from the value of a variable etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Sub RelateiveBttn()` is being called by a Form Button, see comments in code for explanation of what is happening:

```
Sub RelateiveBttn()
    
    ' get the Button
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = Me.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    
    ' get the Range that the Button is in (top left cell of the range ... you can also do .BottomRightCell)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = shp.TopLeftCell
    
    ' get a Range relative to the Button's top left cell
    Dim rngRelativeToButton
    Set rngRelativeToButton = rng.Offset(1, 1).Resize(2, 2)
    
    ' show it worked!
    Debug.Print rngRelativeToButton.Address
End Sub
```

... this just gets you your Range ... doesn't move anything